# Suggestions to implement an automatic counter in Python

Tags: python

In Tex, we have the count variables that get automatically updated each time there is a call to reference, that way the figure counter goes up automatically.

I wanted to do something similar in python for counters, for example, each time I need the counter it already has the new value without me needing to add

```
A+=1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`itertools.count()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count), this is an iterator so use the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) the advance the object to the next value:

```
from itertools import count

yourcounter = count()

next_counted_value = next(yourcounter)
```

You can create a lambda to wrap the function:

```
yourcounter = lambda c=count(): next(c)
```

Or use a [`functools.partial()` object](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

yourcounter = partial(next, count())
```

Then call the object each time:

```
next_counted_value = yourcounter()
```

Comment: Or even `counter = count().next`

Comment: @NiklasB.: indeed, was going to add that, but wanted to make it explicit as to what is happening. :-)

Comment: it seems like `.next()` is not the right function but `.__next__()`

Comment: @jurl the answer was aimed at Python 2. You want to use the `next()` *function* these days. I’ve updated the answer.